# getting error when trying to parse integer

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

Im trying to run an interpreter I made in ocaml and when i to push in a negative value i.e. let e1 = run [PushI -2; PushI 2; LessThan] []. I am getting a syntax error for my parse_int function. I'm trying to write the part of the function that allows for the input of a negative number

```
type stackVal = 
    I of int 

type command = PushI of int 

let rec run (commands : command list) (stack: stackVal list) : stackVal list = 
  match (commands , stack)  with
  | (PushI i :: rest, _              ) -> run rest (I i :: stack)

let to_string (s : stackVal) : string = 
  match s with
  | I i -> string_of_int i 

let parse_command (s:string) : command = 
  match take_while is_alpha (String.trim s) with
  | ("PushI"    , p)  -> let Some i = parse_int (String.trim p)    in PushI i

let parse_int (s : string) : int option = 
  match int_of_string s with 
  | String.get n 0  = '-' -> Some -String.sub n 1 len
  | n         -> Some n
  | exception _ -> None
```

Comment: my previous answer probably misguided you. Your match clause is invalid, the first clause is not necessary `int_of_string "-5"` should work already

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the pattern-matching of your `parse_int` function.

```
match int_of_string s with 
| String.get n 0  = '-' -> Some -String.sub n 1 len
| n         -> Some n
| exception _ -> None
```

The first clause here is invalid as `"String.get n 0  = '-'"` is not an integer constructor. You could write `1` which matches only the integer `1` or `_` whitch matches any integer or `n` which matches any integer and binds it to the name `n` for the rest of the clause. You can have a look at the [manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html) for more informations.

If you wanted to check if the first char of the string is `-` pattern matching is not the right tool to do it, simply use an `if then else`.

However, note that `int_of_string` works just fine on negative integers, so there is no need to do that part by yourself.

Unrelated, but i noticed that you call the `parse_int` in the `parse_command` function. In that case you should define `parse_int` before `parse_command`.